# Drop some Pandas dataframe rows using group based condition

Tags: python, pandas

I've got some data on sales, say, and want to look at how different post codes compare: do some deliver more profitable business than others? So I'm grouping by postcode, and can easily get various stats out on a per postcode basis. However, there are a few very high value jobs which distort the stats, so what I'd like to do is ignore the outliers. For various reasons, what I'd like to do is define the outliers by group: so, for example, drop the rows in the dataframe that are in the top xth percentile of their group, or the top n in their group.

So if I've got the following data frame:

```
>>> df
Out[67]: 
     A         C         D
0  foo -0.536732  0.061055
1  bar  1.470956  1.350996
2  foo  1.981810  0.676978
3  bar -0.072829  0.417285
4  foo -0.910537 -1.634047
5  bar -0.346749 -0.127740
6  foo  0.959957 -1.068385
7  foo -0.640706  2.635910
```

I'd like to be able to have some function, say `drop_top_n(df, group_column, value_column, number_to_drop)` where `drop_top_n(df, "A", "C", 2)` would return

```
     A         C         D
0  foo -0.536732  0.061055
4  foo -0.910537 -1.634047
5  bar -0.346749 -0.127740
7  foo -0.640706  2.635910
```

Using `filter` drops whole groups, rather than parts of groups.

I could iterate through the groups, I suppose, and for each group find out which rows to drop, and then go back to the original dataframe and drop them, but that seems terribly clumsy. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `apply()` method:

```
import pandas as pd
import io


txt="""     A         C         D
0  foo -0.536732  0.061055
1  bar  1.470956  1.350996
2  foo  1.981810  0.676978
3  bar -0.072829  0.417285
4  foo -0.910537 -1.634047
5  bar -0.346749 -0.127740
6  foo  0.959957 -1.068385
7  foo -0.640706  2.635910"""

df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(txt), delim_whitespace=True, index_col=0)

def f(df):
    return df.sort("C").iloc[:-2]
df2 = df.groupby("A", group_keys=False).apply(f)
print df2
```

output:

```
     A         C         D
5  bar -0.346749 -0.127740
4  foo -0.910537 -1.634047
7  foo -0.640706  2.635910
0  foo -0.536732  0.061055
```

If you want original order:

```
print df2.reindex(df.index[df.index.isin(df2.index)])
```

output:

```
    A         C         D
0  foo -0.536732  0.061055
4  foo -0.910537 -1.634047
5  bar -0.346749 -0.127740
7  foo -0.640706  2.635910
```

to get rows above group mean:

```
def f(df):
    return df[df.C>df.C.mean()]
df3 = df.groupby("A", group_keys=False).apply(f)
print df3
```

Comment: I think this is what I wanted. apply() works separately on each group produced by groupby(). I hadn't realised that.

Answer (score 7):

In 0.13 you can use [cumcount](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#enumerate-group-items):

```
In [11]: df[df.sort('C').groupby('A').cumcount(ascending=False) >= 2]  # use .sort_index() to remove UserWarning
Out[11]: 
     A         C         D
0  foo -0.536732  0.061055
4  foo -0.910537 -1.634047
5  bar -0.346749 -0.127740
7  foo -0.640706  2.635910

[4 rows x 3 columns]
```

It may make more sense to sort first:

```
In [21]: df = df.sort('C')

In [22]: df[df.groupby('A').cumcount(ascending=False) >= 2]
Out[22]: 
     A         C         D
4  foo -0.910537 -1.634047
7  foo -0.640706  2.635910
0  foo -0.536732  0.061055
5  bar -0.346749 -0.127740

[4 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: That's interesting, and addresses the specific example I gave very nicely. Is there a more general way of doing it, for example if I wanted to drop (or keep) only those rows that had a value above the group mean or mode? or that were within the top xth percentile?